# print post categories thumbnails into divs for carousel in WP

Tags: php, wordpress

I am printing my post categories thumbnail content fine -- and it outputs; but it shoots out into one `div` determined by the CSS in length, sure I can `overflow:scroll` and have a basic horizontal scroll of my posts (*thumbnails*) but I am **trying to have my `WP` category post content display in a carousel** as seen in this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xYDf4/). My problem consists of how to print my post content (*the thumbs*) to be in separate `<li>` tags as the carousels require for the sections to scroll to. Basically I have 4 series of the below that outputs a slew of my post content thumbnail images based on category ID.

```
                                <div class="feat_wrap_app">
                                <div class="viewport">
                                    <div class="overview">
                                        <ul class="list-unstyled">  
                                            <?php
                                                $buy_featurepost_category_id = get_cat_ID('buy_featurepost');

                                                query_posts('post_type=mobile-experience&category_name=buy&cat=-'.$buy_featurepost_category_id.'&posts_per_page=-1');
                                                //query_posts('post_type=mobile-experience&posts_per_page=-1');


                                                if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                                                    <li class="media">
                                                        <a class="pull-left" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                                                        <?php 
                                                            echo get_small_thumbnail_post('experienceIcon');
                                                        ?>
                                                        </a>
                                                    <!--    <div class="media-body">
                                                            <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                                                            <p><a class="pull-left" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Learn More</a></p>
                                                        </div> -->
                                                    </li>

                                                <?php endwhile; ?>
                                            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>  
                                        </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- // related experiences dynamic app scroll -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array and loop through this array to create the nav

Based on your demo:

```
    <h1>Swipe 2</h1>

<div id='mySwipe' style='max-width:500px;margin:0 auto' class='swipe'>
    <div class='swipe-wrap'>

        <?php
        $buy_featurepost_category_id = get_cat_ID('buy_featurepost');
        $carouselItems = array();
        $postIndex = 0;
        $nbPostPerSlide = 6;
        query_posts('post_type=mobile-experience&category_name=buy&cat=-'.$buy_featurepost_category_id.'&posts_per_page=-1');
        //query_posts('post_type=mobile-experience&posts_per_page=-1');


        if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            $postIndex ++;
            $carouselItems[] = $post->ID;
            ?>

            <?php
            /**
             * open the div slide
             */
            ?>
            <?php if($postIndex === 1):?>
                <div>
            <?php endif; ?>

                <a class="pull-left" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                    <?php
                    echo get_small_thumbnail_post('experienceIcon');
                    ?>
                </a>

            <?php
            /**
             * close the div slide when reaching $nbPostPerSlide
             */
            ?>
            <?php if($postIndex >= $nbPostPerSlide): $postIndex = 0; ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

        <?php
        /**
         * close the div after the loop
         */
        ?>
        <?php if($postIndex && $postIndex < $nbPostPerSlide): ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

    </div>
</div>


<nav>
    <ul id="nav">
        <?php foreach($carouselItems as $index => $item): ?>
            <li><?php echo $index; ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div style='text-align:center;padding-top:20px;'>

    <button onclick='mySwipe.prev()'>prev</button>
    <button onclick='mySwipe.next()'>next</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this is awesome, the only problem with this is it prints just ONE post thumbnail per slide, I would like to print 6.